# Assigning values to array elements based on a look up table

Tags: c#

HI i am writing a c# program where i need to populate a array based on a look up table and set of string arrays with metadata. My lookup table looks like this (Table with key: transmitter, value: Array of receiver)

```
{
    LED1: ["px1","px2","px3"],
    LED2: ["px4","px5","px6"]
}
```

and my meta arrays looks like this **(It is dynamic. Just an example. This comes as a response from DB query.)**

```
var transmitters = new string[] { "LED1", "LED2" };
var receivers = new string[] { "px1", "px2", "px3", "px4", "px5", "px6" };
```

My requirement is

- If the transmitter LED1 or LED2 (or any other transmitter) is present in the lookup table, the value of the transmitter (ie ["px1","px2","px3"]) has to be compared with the receiver which are present in the lookup and led has to be marked yellow.

  - Orphan tranmitter or/ receiver has to be marked red.

**Example**

**LookUp**

```
{
        LED1: ["px1", "px2", "px3"],
        LED2: ["px5", "px8"]
}
```

Tranmitters and receivers

```
var transmitters = new string[] { "led1", "led2" };
var receivers = new string[] { "px1", "px2", "px3", "px4", "px5", "px6" };
```

the result should be a list as

```
led1-yellow
px1-yellow
px2-yellow
px3-yellow
led2-yellow
px5-yellow
px4-red
px6-red.
```

I have written code that works

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var transmitters = new string[] { "led1", "led2" };
        var receivers = new string[] { "px1", "px2", "px3", "px4", "px5", "px6" };
        var lookup = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() { { "led1", new string[] { "px1", "px2", "px3" } }, { "led2", new string[] { "px5", "px8" } } };

        var blocks = new List<Block>();
        var blocksTracker = new List<string>();

        foreach (var transmitter in transmitters)
        {
            if (lookup.ContainsKey(transmitter))
            {
                var receiverLookup = lookup[transmitter];
                var intersection = receivers.Intersect(receiverLookup).ToArray();
                if (intersection.Length > 0)
                {
                    blocks.Add(new Block() { Id = transmitter, status = "yellow" });
                    blocksTracker.Add(transmitter);
                    foreach (var receiver in intersection)
                    {
                        blocks.Add(new Block() { Id = receiver, status = "yellow" });
                        blocksTracker.Add(receiver);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    blocks.Add(new Block() { Id = transmitter, status = "red" });
                    blocksTracker.Add(transmitter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to c# and i wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this. Please help. You can see the working fiddle [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d3E7n0)

Comment: Code looks OK to me.

Comment: Your question might get an answer at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/